# Access data in a nested df

Tags: python, yahoo-api

I am using a library to get stock data.  The data is then put into a df but in a nested form. I want to get data from two specific columns but the date column key is not recognised.

```
import numpy as np
from yahooquery import Ticker

mydata = Ticker('WMT', asynchronous=True)
# the above returns a yahoo.ticker.Ticker object)

df = mydata.history(period = '1m', interval = '1d'
# this creates a df with daily closing info for the month
```

The output looks like
[image]

If then look at the keys using df.keys() I get the following:
Index(['low', 'close', 'high', 'open', 'volume', 'adjclose', 'dividends'], dtype='object')

I want to be able to have a flat df with two columns - date and close.  How do I get that result? how do I even access the data in the 'date' column?

I am guessing the Ticker object is in json form but how can I tell? Unfortunately pd.json_normal(mydata) gives a 'NotImplementedError'.

The yahooquery library can be found at https://pypi.org/project/yahooquery/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out, and I believe you can use [pandas.DataFrame.reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Code:

```
df.reset_index()[["date","close"]]
```

Output:

[image]